# Zend: no database addapter present error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am following a tutorial to make a login form. If the user is authenticated, simply redirect the user to the Home page. If login fails, show the error. I have the error

```
No database adapter present
Stack trace:

#0 \Zend_Include\library\Zend\Auth\Adapter\DbTable.php(139): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->_setDbAdapter(NULL)
#1 \application\controllers\AccountController.php(24): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->__construct(NULL)
```

I reread the tutorial, but the code is identical and I have no idea why I have this error.

my loginAction() in Account Controller

```
        $form = new Application_Model_FormLogin(array('action'=>'/account/login'));

        // if the form is submitted
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            if ($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {

                $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
                $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db);
                $authAdapter->setTableName('accounts');
                $authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('email');
                $authAdapter->setCredentialColumn('pswd');
                $authAdapter->setCredentialTreament('MD5(?) and confirmed=1');

                $authAdapter->setIdentity($form->getValue('email'));
                $authAdapter->setCredential($form->getValue('pswd'));

                $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
                $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

                // did the user successfully login
                $account = new Application_Model_Account();
                $lastLogin = $account->findByEmail($form->getValue('email'));
                $lastLogin->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $lastLogin->save();

                $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('You are logged in');
                $this->redirector('Index', 'index');

            }else{
                . . .
            }
        }else{
            . . .
        }

        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwoing, before you use Zend_Db_Table:

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory ( 'PDO_MYSQL', $objDbConfig);
AbstractTable::setDefaultAdapter ( $dbAdapter );
```